# Highcharts: How to stop the service live chart (highcharts) in angular when I open new component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I work with framework Highcharts and angular I have a problem if I open new component the live chart continue running.

```
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live Data (Rows JSON)'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Data input from a remote JSON file'
        },

        data: {
            rowsURL: 'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/time-rows.json',
            firstRowAsNames: false,
            enablePolling: true
        }
    });




<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

live Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/livedata-rows

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in Angular? You can use this demo as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/543l0p0qq4.

Comment: Hi @WojciechChmiel , the method subscription not working to stop running the live chart if open new component continue run in the console(network).this example:https://codesandbox.io/s/m7x9795928

Comment: Unfortunately, your example doesn't show the exact issue. I can see the chart component with live data from the url and subscription that subscribe to nothing. So what are your expectations by using `this.sub.unsubscribe();` on destroy lifecycle?

Comment: I use subscription for kill the service live chart  as the function clearInterval() when I open new component.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work like that.